# Finding islands of ones with zeros boundary

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I am trying to find islands of numbers in a matrix.
By an island, I mean a rectangular area where ones are connected with each other either horizontally, vertically or diagonally including the boundary layer of zeros

Suppose I have this matrix:

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

By boundary layer, I mean row 2 and 7, and column 3 and 10 for island#1.

This is shown below:

[image: explanation]

I want the row and column indices of the islands. So for the above matrix, the desired output is:

```
isl{1}= {[2 3 4 5 6 7];          % row indices of island#1
       [3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10]}       % column indices of island#1

isl{2}= {[2 3 4 5 6 7];          % row indices of island#2
       [12 13 14 15 16 17]};     % column indices of island#2

isl{3} ={[9 10 11 12];           % row indices of island#3
       [2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11];} % column indices of island#3
```

It doesn't matter which island is detected first.

While I know that the `[r,c] = find(matrix)` function can give the row and column indices of ones but I have no clues on how to detect the connected ones since they can be connected in horizontal, vertical and diagonal order. 
Any ideas on how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Just check all the sides. If it contains 1 aswell, find next 1, etc.

Comment: as I am not so familiar with matlab, I can not give you good code. However you could create a set containing all boundaries around any one that occurs, then merge all the ones which overlap, expanding the boundaries accordingly.

Comment: @Chris A pseudo code will do, if you can suggest that

Comment: Try to make your own code first. We are here for doing homework for you.

Comment: @MarkBaijens I am trying that

Comment: Merging boundaries won't work. It is possible that the boundaries of two islands are overlap each other but they are still two separated islands.

Comment: @Likeunknown what have you made yourself then? We might be able to hint you in the right direction.

Comment: @MarkBaijens While detecting ones, the first thing comes to mind is the `find` function but since it's a matrix of ones and zeros. `find` ends up reproducing the same matrix if I try to search ones row by row or column by column. Now I am trying to go for the linear indices at the moment. And searching in the viscinity of the each linear index. I'll update my post if I come up with some working code

Comment: What happens in the case when two islands share a surrounding zero or one at the border? Or is this case assumed never to happen?

Comment: @Wolfie This is possible. In that case, that boundary will be included in both islands.

Comment: What if two ones are connected diagonally (or vertically/horizontally), but (for simplicity's sake) they are 2 rectangular islands which are otherwise full enclosed. Does this make them a single island or two?

Comment: @Wolfie if two ones are connected in any way; horizontally, vertically  or diagonally, it makes them one island

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. However they leave me confused about "island 1". There is a 1 surrounded by 0s (row 6, column 4), should this not be "island 4"?

Comment: @Wolfie sorry for the late reply. What I mean by an island is the *rectangular* area that covers all the connected ones. See this picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QQR7L.png The red rectangle is the rectangular area with all the connected ones. The orange rectangle is the area with the boundary layer. Please let me know it still does not make any good sense. I'll try to rephrase/clarify

Comment: What is the expected output for the following [example](https://pastebin.com/58jd7sng) or for [this](https://pastebin.com/uQdUfwyH)?

Comment: @rahnema1 `isl{1}={ [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]; [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]}`, `isl{2}={[3,4,5,6,7]; [3,4,5,6,7]}` for the first link. For the second link, I am afraid that I didn't think of such a case but it's possible and adding that case might make the existing answers invalid. But for that it will be the whole matrix.

Comment: And for [this](https://pastebin.com/4Tr4qJja)?

Comment: @rahnema1 to rephrase in a better way. Boundary layer can have zeros only, otherwise it is not boundary. For this, it is also the complete matrix

Comment: Okay, one more... what about [this](https://pastebin.com/PisdZYvP)? The component on the right prevents the component on the left from having a zero boundary. Do you want the two components to be merged into one island, or only return the smaller component as an island?

Comment: @beaker Merge into one island. I am really out of ideas on how to achieve that. The posted answers are somewhat useful though.  :-(

Comment: I've got a solution that handles all of your cases except the first example from @rahnema1 [here](https://pastebin.com/58jd7sng). In this case it seems to be contradictory to have two islands since one component is inside the bounding box of the other. If you're okay having this case reduced to one island, I'll go ahead and post my answer.

Comment: @beaker If all other cases are covered, I'm okay to have  that particular case reduced to one island.  Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finding the connected components and their bounding boxes is the easy part. The more difficult part is merging the bounding boxes into islands.

#### Bounding Boxes

First the easy part.

```
function bBoxes = getIslandBoxes(lMap)
   % find bounding box of each candidate island
   % lMap is a logical matrix containing zero or more connected components
   bw = bwlabel(lMap);   % label connected components in logical matrix
   bBoxes = struct2cell(regionprops(bw, 'BoundingBox'));   % get bounding boxes
   bBoxes = cellfun(@round, bBoxes, 'UniformOutput', false);   % round values
end
```

The values are rounded because the bounding boxes returned by `regionprops` lies *outside* its respective component on the grid lines rather than the cell center, and we need integer values to use as subscripts into the matrix. For example, a component that looks like this:

```
0   0   0
0   1   0
0   0   0
```

will have a bounding box of

```
[ 1.5000   1.5000   1.0000   1.0000 ]
```

which we round to

```
[ 2  2  1  1]
```

#### Merging

Now the hard part. First, the merge condition:

- We merge bounding box `b2` into bounding box `b1` if `b2` and the *island* of `b1` (including the boundary layer) have a non-null intersection.

This condition ensures that bounding boxes are merged when one component is wholly or partially inside the bounding box of another, but it also catches the edge cases when a bounding box is within the zero boundary of another. Once all of the bounding boxes are merged, they are guaranteed to have a boundary of all zeros (or border the edge of the matrix), otherwise the nonzero value in its boundary would have been merged.

Since merging involves deleting the merged bounding box, the loops are done backwards so that we don't end up indexing non-existent array elements.

Unfortunately, making one pass through the array comparing each element to all the others is insufficient to catch all cases. To signal that all of the possible bounding boxes have been merged into islands, we use a flag called `anyMerged` and loop until we get through one complete iteration without merging anything.

```
function mBoxes = mergeBoxes(bBoxes)
   % find bounding boxes that intersect, and merge them
   mBoxes = bBoxes;
   % merge bounding boxes that overlap
   anyMerged = true;   % flag to show when we've finished
   while (anyMerged)
      anyMerged = false;   % no boxes merged on this iteration so far...
      for box1 = numel(mBoxes):-1:2
         for box2 = box1-1:-1:1
            % if intersection between bounding boxes is > 0, merge
            % the size of box1 is increased b y 1 on all sides...
            %    this is so that components that lie  within the borders
            %    of another component, but not inside the bounding box,
            %    are merged
            if (rectint(mBoxes{box1} + [-1 -1 2 2], mBoxes{box2}) > 0)
               coords1 = rect2corners(mBoxes{box1});
               coords2 = rect2corners(mBoxes{box2});

               minX = min(coords1(1), coords2(1));
               minY = min(coords1(2), coords2(2));
               maxX = max(coords1(3), coords2(3));
               maxY = max(coords1(4), coords2(4));

               mBoxes{box2} = [minX, minY, maxX-minX+1, maxY-minY+1];   % merge
               mBoxes(box1) = [];   % delete redundant bounding box

               anyMerged = true;   % bounding boxes merged: loop again
               break;
            end
         end
      end
   end
end
```

The merge function uses a small utility function that converts rectangles with the format `[x y width height]` to a vector of subscripts for the top-left, bottom-right corners `[x1 y1 x2 y2]`. (This was actually used in another function to check that an island had a zero border, but as discussed above, this check is unnecessary.)

```
function corners = rect2corners(rect)
   % change from rect = x, y, width, height
   %       to corners = x1, y1, x2, y2
   corners = [rect(1), ...
              rect(2), ...
              rect(1) + rect(3) - 1, ...
              rect(2) + rect(4) - 1];
end
```

#### Output Formatting and Driver Function

The return value from `mergeBoxes` is a cell array of rectangle objects. If you find this format useful, you can stop here, but it's easy to get to the format requested with ranges of rows and columns for each island:

```
function rRanges = rect2range(bBoxes, mSize)
   % convert rect = x, y, width, height to
   %        range = y:y+height-1; x:x+width-1
   % and expand range by 1 in all 4 directions to include zero border,
   % making sure to stay within borders of original matrix
   rangeFun = @(rect) {max(rect(2)-1,1):min(rect(2)+rect(4),mSize(1));...
                       max(rect(1)-1,1):min(rect(1)+rect(3),mSize(2))};
   rRanges = cellfun(rangeFun, bBoxes, 'UniformOutput', false);
end
```

All that's left is a main function to tie all of the others together and we're done.

```
function theIslands = getIslandRects(m)
   % get rectangle around each component in map
   lMap = logical(m);

   % get the bounding boxes of candidate islands
   bBoxes = getIslandBoxes(lMap);

   % merge bounding boxes that overlap
   bBoxes = mergeBoxes(bBoxes);

   % convert bounding boxes to row/column ranges
   theIslands = rect2range(bBoxes, size(lMap));

end
```

Here's a run using the sample matrix given in the question:

```
M =
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   1
   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   1   1   1   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   0   0   0   1   1   1   1
   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
>> getIslandRects(M)
ans =
{
  [1,1] =
  {
    [1,1] =
        9   10   11   12
    [2,1] =
        2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11
  }
  [1,2] =
  {
    [1,1] =
       2   3   4   5   6   7
    [2,1] =
        3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10
  }
  [1,3] =
  {
    [1,1] =
       2   3   4   5   6   7
    [2,1] =
       12   13   14   15   16   17
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look at the BoundingBox and ConvexHull stats returned by regionprops:

```
a = imread('circlesBrightDark.png');
bw = a < 100;
s = regionprops('table',bw,'BoundingBox','ConvexHull')
```

https://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/regionprops.html

Comment: can you please explain the usage with my matrix to get the desired result?

Answer (score 1):

Quite easy!

Just use [`bwboundaries`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwboundaries.html) to get the boundaries of each of the blobs. you can then just get the `min` and `max` in each `x` and `y` direction of each boundary to build your box.

Comment: I don't know why it is downvoted since it has brought me very close. However with this, there are some false detections too. `B = bwboundaries(matrix);` detects three islands correctly (without the boundary layer which can be added later though) but there are three false detections too. can you suggest how that can be avoided.

Comment: @Likeunknown I have no idea why it was down voted nop.....You can use the second option, the connectivity to make sure the objects in diagonal are considered the same object. However there are 2 "1"s alone in your first island. I have no idea what are the rules to make them part of island 1. Perhaps you need a small check to say "if the boundary of this island is totally within another one, then its part of that other one". This will require a for loop and some ifs, but shouldnt be too hard

Answer (score 1):

Use image dilation and regionprops

```
mat = [...
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1;
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1;
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
mat=logical(mat);
dil_mat=imdilate(mat,true(2,2)); %here we make bridges to 1 px away ones
l_mat=bwlabel(dil_mat,8);
bb = regionprops(l_mat,'BoundingBox');
bb = struct2cell(bb); bb = cellfun(@(x) fix(x), bb, 'un',0);
isl = cellfun(@(x) {max(1,x(2)):min(x(2)+x(4),size(mat,1)),...
                    max(1,x(1)):min(x(1)+x(3),size(mat,2))},bb,'un',0);
```

Comment: The down side of dilation is you can connect two regions into one if they are separated by a single row or column of zeroes.

Comment: If you see the picture of island#1, there is unconnected (1px gap) pixel at bottom left. I thought that island separation should be at least by 2 px

Comment: However, the last string can be simplified, bounding box cannot exceed image limits

Comment: According to the description, islands should be 8-connected nearest neighbors. I suspect that errant 1 should be its own island.

Comment: If so, dilation is not needed, yes. The other change is 
bb = cellfun(@(x) fix(x) + [-1 -1 1 1], bb, 'un',0);
I always prefer visual example to text desciption

Comment: Thanks for answer. Btw your answer merges two islands if they share a common zeros boundary. But still useful.